# Photo Library view stays on screen after choosing an image with UIImagePickerController

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

After I choose a picture through the UIImagePickerController interface from the Photo Library, the Photo Library view stays displayed, even though I've called **dismissModelViewControllerAnimated** in **imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo**.

Has anyone seen this? These are the three relevant methods I'm using:

```
- (IBAction)choosePictureFromLibrary:(id)sender {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
        UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error accessing Photo Library" message:@"This device does not support a Photo Library." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage*)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary*)editingInfo {   
    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Picture picked!" message:@"You picked a picture!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController*)picker {   
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I would have thought that calling imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo would completely dismiss the Photo Library view, but it doesn't seem to. Is there anything else I have to do to make it go away?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to access the viewController of the picker not the picker itself.  Try this line instead.

```
[[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much, this has been driving me crazy!

Answer (score 3):

You can just call

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to dismiss any modal view controller on top of the current view.

This makes sense since you present the view controller by calling:

```
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Comment: +1 but see my answer for updated answer as these have been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update to the answers to this

```
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

has been deprecated in `iOS 6.0` so you now need to use.

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Not a huge change but for anyone that looks at this question and they are using iOS 6.0 they will need an updated answer.

```
 [self presentModalViewController:filePicker animated:YES];
```

has also been deprecated in favor of

```
 [self presentViewController:filePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```