# iPhone Structure ViewController

Tags: iphone, xcode, view, controller, structure

I am designing an iPhone application with a home page. This page has multiple buttons (6) that go to different things.

2 buttons are a simple view that just have some information and go back to the home screen. The next button opens up an email and I believe that will just be one view, so not a whole lot different than the other two.

Here is where it gets complicated. One button will take a picture, and another will select one from the library. Once that is done it will edit it and create an object that I will create. That object will be stored in an array, which will be opened by the last button one the home page and a UITableViewController will control that.

My **first question** is should I use a navigation based view controller or just a view controller that I can create myself? Or should I use something that I don't even know about?

Please Help!!! And if you help a sincere thank you!

EDIT:

Well i tried it my own way first and the only issue i'm having is this code

```
- (void) displayView:(int)intNewView { 
    NSLog(@"%i", intNewView);
    [home.view removeFromSuperview];
    Instructions *i = [[Instructions alloc]init];
    instructions = i; 
    [self.view insertSubview:instructions.view atIndex:0]; 
}
```

It is in my SwitchClass, which controls the Main Window's view. I know it is working there because when it first runs the switch class directs it to the home screen. I know the method is being called because the console is displaying the NSLog thing, but it just won't switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the fact that you have 6 buttons, I would try and use a UITabBarController for what you are trying to do; it would seem more natural to me (but you should find a way to reduce you 6 button to 5, otherwise they will not be displayed all at once).

Otherwise, a UINavigationController seems fine to me. For each button you push a new controller to deal with that button functionality, then you pop back. It should work easily.

EDIT:

have you tried with?

```
[self.view addSubview:instructions.view];
```

Comment: Well i tried it my own way first and the only issue i'm having is this code
    - (void) displayView:(int)intNewView {
     NSLog(@"%i", intNewView);
     [home.view removeFromSuperview];
     Instructions *i = [[Instructions alloc]init];
     instructions = i;
     [self.view insertSubview:instructions.view atIndex:0];
    }
It is in my SwitchClass, which controls the Main Window's view. I know it is working there because when it first runs the switch class directs it to the home screen. I know the method is being called because the console is displaying the NSLog thing. It just won't switch

Comment: If you are taking advantage of ARC in your code, then you do not need to release anything (and actually, you cannot).

Answer (score 0):

Your first question Yes you should use navigation based controller  ... so when you press any button will open the other view controller with animation.. also Navigation Based Controller keep track of the parent controller if you have any created objects will be retained in the parent view controller that is the root of the Navigation.

here is the steps that you should use.

1-Create Navigation controller in the main application delegate and make it's root is the view controller.

2-when you push the view controller that have 6 buttons .

3- you can check this link for get photo album also if you have changed the source type to camera then you can get the image...
[Photo Libaray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676039/photo-library-view-stays-on-screen-after-choosing-an-image-with-uiimagepickercon?rq=1)

4- once you get the image you can add it to NSMutableArray that exist on the NavigationViewController root in your case will be the view which have the 6 buttons.

5-sice every time you want to view the array which contain the photos you will initialize the data source of the uitableviewcontroller with the array that you save photos on.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is coming from one of two places:

As I understand it, these are all different View Controllers, correct? And they have their own xib files? If that is true, then calling:

> Instructions *i = [[Instructions alloc]init];

is insufficient. You need to use

```
 Instructions *i = [[Instructions alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"Instructions"];
```

in order to include that view that you have already constructed in the interface builder.

The other thing I see potentially going wrong is that you are inserting all the views at the same index. Think of the index as a layer in photoshop. If you want the new view to be visible overtop of the last one, then it needs to be a higher index. This is handled automatically if you use `addSubview:` instead of `insertSubview: atIndex:`